Extension Property does not imply Normality.
An algebraic extension $F\subset E$ has the restriction property if for every $F$-algebra automorphism $\sigma\in\operatorname{Aut}_F(E)$ and every intermediate extension $F\subset M\subset E$, $\sigma(M)=M$ and that $\sigma|_M:M\to M$ is also an automorphism.
An algebraic extension $F\subset E$ has the extension property if for every algebraic extension $E\subset L$ and every $F$-algebra map $f\in\operatorname{Mor}_F(E,L)$, there is an $F$-algebra automorphism $\tau:L\to L$ extending $f$, i.e. $\tau|_E=f$.
It is well-known that an algebraic extension $F\subset E$ is a normal extension iff it has both the restriction property and the extension property. The extension $\Bbb Q\subset \Bbb Q\left[\sqrt[3]{2}\right]$ has only identity for its automorphism group, so that it has the restriction property but is not normal. This extension cannot also have the extension property, or else it would be normal.
Is there an algebraic extension $F\subset E$ with the extension property but not normal? I believe there should be an example to this.

I am not sure I'm reading your claims in the intended way. Consider $F=\Bbb{Q}$, $E=\Bbb{Q}(\root3\of2,\omega), \omega=e^{2\pi i/3}$, $M=\Bbb{Q}(\root3\of2)$. Then $E/F$ is normal, but $E$ has an $F$-automorphism $\sigma$ that maps $\root3\of2$ to $\omega\root3\of2$, so $\sigma$ doesn't map $M$ to itself, and therefore $E/F$ doesn't have the restriction property.

Similarly, if $F=\Bbb{Q}$, $E=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$, then $E/F$ is normal, but it doesn't have the extension property. Consider $L=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{5+\sqrt2})$. Then $\sqrt2\in L$, so there is a map of $F$-algebras $f:E\to L$ such that $f(\sqrt2)=-\sqrt2$. But $f$ does not extend to an automorphism of $L$, because such an extension would need to map $\sqrt{5+\sqrt2}$ to $\sqrt{5-\sqrt2}$, but the latter number is not in $L$.

I think you got some of these things backwards. If $M/F$ is a normal extension, $M\subseteq E$, and $\sigma:E\to E$ is an automorphism of $F$-algebras, then $\sigma(M)=M$. I suspect that could be the restriction property (assuming it is related to normality). Similarly. if $L/F$ is normal, and $E$ is an intermediate field, then any $F$-algebra homomorphism $f:E\to L$ extends to an automorphism of $L$. Please check your sources for the correct definitions.

To be a normal the extension has to be finite.
Take $P_n = X^n-1$ and $A_n = \{\alpha_1,…,\alpha_n \in \overline{\mathbb{Q}}: P_n(\alpha_i) = 0, i=1,…,n\}$. Then if
$A = \bigcup_{n\ge 1}A_n$ we can consider the extension $\mathbb{Q}(A)/\mathbb{Q} $. Thus $\mathbb{Q}(A)$ satisfy the extension property but is not normal because is not the splitting field of any polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$.
